# What is nextMessageIdToRead parameter in browseQueue() method of AndesAdminServicePortTypeProxy class

Tags: jms, message-queue, wso2, wso2-message-broker

I am using on WSO2 Message Broker as a message brokering system in my project. To get the queue browse information, I generated client from **AndesAdminServics WSDL** and I am trying to call browseQueue() method of **AndesAdminServicePortTypeProxy class** from my api. Generated browseQueue() method is

```
public org.wso2.carbon.andes.admin.internal.xsd.Message[] browseQueue(java.lang.String queueName, java.lang.Long nextMessageIdToRead, java.lang.Integer maxMsgCount) throws java.rmi.RemoteException{
    if (andesAdminServicePortType == null)
      _initAndesAdminServicePortTypeProxy();
    return andesAdminServicePortType.browseQueue(queueName, nextMessageIdToRead, maxMsgCount);
  }
```

browseQueue() method takes three parameter -
java.lang.String queueName, java.lang.Long nextMessageIdToRead, java.lang.Integer maxMsgCount

I understand parameter queueName, but i am not getting, What does parameters nextMessageIdToRead and maxMsgCount  represent. At the time of browseQueue() method call, What should i pass as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the actual admin service code. There it contains more information
https://github.com/wso2/andes/blob/b721d5cccfd9896ec871610b7938ba96785b202c/modules/andes-core/management/common/src/main/java/org/wso2/andes/management/common/mbeans/QueueManagementInformation.java#L162

1. name = "queueName", description = "Name of queue to browse messages"
2. name = "lastMsgId", description = "Browse message this onwards"
3. name = "maxMsgCount", description = "Maximum message count per request"